# Is it appropriate to store an array of size 64 in register for Nvidia GPU?

Tags: cuda

To demonstrate the question, let us consider the following example. Suppose I have two arrays `A[16][64]` and `B[16][N][64]` and I want to calculate `ans[i][j][N]=f(A[i], B[j][N])` where `f` is a function. I will write a cuda kernel with 256 threads in a block, each calculating for one pair `(i,j)` all the `ans[i][j][k]`s .

The most classic approach will load `A` into shared memory first. However, I find that since `A` will be used N times in a thread, after loading to shared memory I can further load `A[i]` into register to speed up calculating `f(A[i], B[j][N])`. It is common sense that register is faster than shared memory.

I have looked up the document [Compute Capability](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) and find that each thread can have at most 255 registers which is larger than 64, so it is OK to use 64 registers. But I also hear a term called register pressure, which says that using many registers may be slow. Furthermore, I find that the compiler often limits the number of registers, and will use local memory if the number of registers exceeds the limit.

Based on the above fact, I have a lot of confusion. For example, should I use register instead of shared memory in this case ? Does register pressure really appear in this case? How much faster is visiting register than shared memory? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .... should I use register instead of shared memory in this case ?

There is no way to "use" registers. The compiler determines how registers are allocated using a lot of sophisticated code analysis and heuristics. The programmer has no control over this. The compiler will spill to local memory as it sees fit.

> Does register pressure really appear in this case?

Impossible to say. Obviously if you increase the register footprint of a kernel, the maximum number of threads per SM will decrease at some point. Whether that effects performance is code and device specific and requires benchmarking data. You have provided details of none of those three things

> How much faster is visiting register than shared memory?

The general rule some years ago (too lazy to look up the Vasily Volkov analysis) was that there was about 10 times higher register bandwidth compared to shared memory